# SQL Server index on a BIT non-selective column

Tags: sql-server, indexing

We have quite large table (300k rows) with a lot of columns (80+). One of the columns is a bit field which marks whether the row is deleted:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblProject]
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ...
    [Deleted] [BIT] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblProject] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

Some developer who no longer works with us, has created 3 indexes on `Deleted` column:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tblProject_Deleted] 
ON [dbo].[tblProject] ([Deleted] ASC)
INCLUDE ([Id], [FK1Id], [FK2Id], [FK3Id], [SomeDecimalColumn]) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tblProject_Deleted2] 
ON [dbo].[tblProject] ([Deleted] ASC)
INCLUDE ([Id], [FK1Id], [FK2Id], [FK4Id], [FK5Id]) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tblProject_Deleted3] 
ON [dbo].[tblProject] ([Deleted] ASC)
INCLUDE ([Id], [FK1Id], [FK2Id], [FK4Id]) ON [PRIMARY]
```

My first question is - the third index seems to be totally covered by index 2. Am I right that such index does not bring anything valuable and can be removed?

The data distribution for `Deleted` column looks like this:

```
99.9% rows contain 0
0.1% rows contain 1
```

We have a lot of queries joining with `tblProject` on various foreign keys, all of them include `WHERE Deleted = 0` clause. As you can see this predicate hardly removes any rows from the working set.

According to my knowledge and the following links:

[Sql Server Index on Bit fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607332/sql-server-index-on-bit-fields)

[Should I index a bit field in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231125/should-i-index-a-bit-field-in-sql-server)

[Index on a bit column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964428/index-on-a-bit-column)

The query optimizer will never utilize such indexes as the usage of these indexes would not reduce the working set at all. It is just more efficient to do a table scan than to read the index.

They would be useful if our queries contained `WHERE Deleted = 1` clause. But they don't.

So can all these indexes be safely deleted?

Or is the query optimizer smart enough to use the index to quickly find the rows where Deleted=1 and then remove them from the working set to achieve Deleted=0?

I am unable to check all the queries we have in the system to confirm that the indexes are not utilized. I would like to delete these indexes but I don't want to reduce the system performance. Could deleting them affect the performance negatively?

Comment: [There's a view for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql).

Comment: BlitzIndex could give you some useful details

Comment: *filtered* indexes using that column in the filter would be the more obvious thing to do...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: but such filtered index will contain 99.9% of rows (all the queries search for not deleted rows). Does it make sense to create it? This column is just not selective at all.